# Are short-sell allowed in conic formulation of Markowitz optimization?

Tags: optimization, mosek

Sorry to ask a question about the basic Markowitz portfolio optimization. The example is from Mosek's example book.

The basic Markowitz portfolio optimization is formulated as:
[image: here]

The book mentioned we can simply remove the constraint $x \ge 0$ to allow short-sell in this formulation.

However, my question is about the conic formulation of original problem, which was given as: 
[image]

Assuming we similarly remove the constraint $x \ge 0$ in this conic formulation, will it allow short-sell, i.e. $x \lt 0$? My feeling is yes since the cone $Q^{n+1}$ only requires $x_0$ which is $\gamma$ to be non-negative. I tried to change the sample codes below to remove the non-negativity constraint.
[image]

But the results seems to be the same. Just would like to confirm if my understanding is correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, of course you can remove the $x\ge0$ constraint if you like.

Maybe your data is such that that short selling is not worthwhile.
Hard to say.

Comment: Removing the positive domain constraint breaks the budget constraint.

Comment: Thanks all for answering. Master @ErlingMOSEK, thanks for your confirmation. 8 -)